What is the "Holy Commandment" as spoken of in 2 Peter 2:21?
"For it had been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than, after they have known it, to turn from the holy commandment delivered unto them."
I am just trying to understand what the "holy commandment" is and how we can truly understand it using scripture. If anyone could help that would be great!

The context of this verse speaks of the seduction of some people who "have escaped the pollutions of the world through the full knowledge  of the Lord and Savior Jesus Christ". Yet however, the previous verses addresses false teachers. The importance of this chapter is then focusing overall upon false teachers.
From this context surrounding this verse alone, it appears that the commandment is one that was handed over to them. This word used for handed over is παραδίδωμι - "to deliver verbally"; "to give over to one's power or use"; "to give into the hands". Nothing more is given about this command.
Reading into the next chapter 3, we see this scripture which may help this context:

Dear friends, this is the second letter I’m writing to you. In both
letters I’m trying to refresh your memory. I want you to remember the
words spoken in the past by the holy prophets and what the Lord and
Savior commanded you through your apostles. (2 Peter 3:1,2)

This above verse points to what the audience knows was commanded by the Lord Jesus through the NT apostles.
Especially remembering the context of pointing out what false teachers are, Peter then gave the results of their students - "the latter end is worse for them than the beginning".

For when they speak great swelling words of emptiness, they allure
through the lusts of the flesh, through lewdness, the ones who have
actually escaped from those who live in error. While they promise them
liberty, they themselves are slaves of corruption; for by whom a
person is overcome, by him also he is brought into bondage. For if,
after they have escaped the pollutions of the world through the
knowledge of the Lord and Savior Jesus Christ, they are again
entangled in them and overcome, the latter end is worse for them than
the beginning. For it would have been better for them not to have
known the way of righteousness, than having known it, to turn from the
holy commandment delivered to them. But it has happened to them
according to the true proverb: “A dog returns to his own vomit,” and,
“a sow, having washed, to her wallowing in the mire.”
2 Peter 2:18-22

Since this scripture does not say which command, we can only assume the Lord Jesus' command(s), since this person returning to the vomit and mire had actually escaped from error through the knowledge of the Lord Jesus. Do we need to know which command if "the way of righteousness" was known through the possession of this command and the action of this seduced person was to turn from it?
'meaning of full knowledge'
'to turn back'
Shepherd's Note: to turn from the light is not the same as stumbling around in it or learning to take the command into the depths of our hearts like James talked about in James 1:16-25 and Jesus talked about in the sower of the seed in Matthew 13. Further encouragement from Peter in 2 Peter 3 (the next chapter after all of this talk about false teachers) is meant to help us to run to safety within our Lord's clear commands and grace.

Thank you for your comment its much appreaciated!

The commandment is not specified, but what it pertains to is fairly clear:

(vs. 18) they mouth empty, boastful words and, by appealing to the
lustful desires of the flesh, they entice people who are just escaping
from those who live in error.

The author writes in opposition to false teachers who misuse Paul's "gospel of freedom" to seduce new Christians into a tradition of sexual libertinism. See 3:16b

His (Paul's) letters contain some things that are hard to understand,
which ignorant and unstable people distort...to their own destruction.

The specific sins were are talking about are hinted at in 2:13-14:

They are blots and blemishes, reveling in their pleasures while they
feast with you. {some ancient manuscripts say in their love feasts}  With eyes full of adultery, they never stop
sinning; they seduce the unstable; they are experts in greed—an
accursed brood!

Writing in the Jewish Annotated New Testament, Mark Greenwald opines that the holy commandment here is a reference to the moral commandments of the OT in general. However, I think we can narrow it down further to the laws regarding sexual morality : in other words the laws dealing with the sin of lust.  Considering the description of the eyes of the false teachers in vs 13, if we were to identify one specific commandment, it would be "thou shalt not commit adultery."

The phrase "the holy commandment" in 2 Peter 2:21 can be understood as referring to agape love (ἀγάπη), the highest foundation of Christian life. This interpretation is supported by the following arguments:

Progression in Christian Virtues (2 Peter 1:5-7):
The apostle Peter outlines a progression of virtues that culminates in agape love as the pinnacle of spiritual maturity. He exhorts his readers to add to their faith (πίστιν) virtues such as knowledge, self-control, perseverance, godliness, brotherly kindness, and ultimately agape love (ἀγάπην). This love, more than an emotion, represents a selfless, sacrificial commitment to the well-being of others, rooted in the divine nature (2 Peter 1:4).

The Understanding Between Jesus and Peter (John 21:14-17):
After the resurrection, Jesus confronts Peter with the question, "Do you love me?" Twice, Jesus uses the verb agape (ἀγαπᾷς), while Peter responds with phileo (φιλῶ), a term for brotherly affection. On the third instance, Jesus adjusts his question to phileo, acknowledging Peter's current level of understanding. This dialogue highlights agape love as central to Peter’s calling and the Christian mission.

The Contrast Between Agape and Lusts (ἐπιθυμίας):
In 2 Peter 1:4, Peter speaks of escaping the corruption in the world caused by lusts (ἐπιθυμίας). These lusts are in direct opposition to agape, characterized by selfishness and indulgence in one’s desires. In 2 Peter 2:10, 2:18, and 3:3, lusts are described as defining traits of false teachers and scoffers, contrasting sharply with the self-giving and sacrificial nature of agape love.


Thus, the "holy commandment" in 2 Peter 2:21 is best understood as agape love. This commandment is not merely an ethical directive but the essence of spiritual transformation that allows believers to partake in the divine nature (2 Peter 1:4). To turn away from this commandment and return to worldly lusts (2 Peter 2:22) is a spiritual tragedy, representing a rejection of the very foundation of Christian life.

Wow what a beautiful comment! Thank you very much.
